# difference between subscription/pull_message_operation_count and subscription/pull_request_count

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I need to check if my subscription has done any pull in last 15 days or not, which metric should i consider?

I'm new to this google pubsub stackdriver metrics and getting confused with them.
can anyone tell me difference between these metrics:

subscription/pull_message_operation_count
subscription/pull_request_count
subscription/pull_ack_message_operation_count
subscription/pull_ack_request_count

Answer (score 2):

The difference between "operation_count" and "request_count" is due to the fact that both pull and ack allows for batching, i.e., a pull response can return multiple messages and an ack request can contain the IDs of multiple messages to ack. For pull, `subscription/pull_request_count` would be the number of pull requests you make. `subscription/pull_message_operation_count` would be the number of messages returned to you in responses to pull requests. Similarly, `subscription/pull_ack_request_count` would be the number of calls you make to ack. `subscription/pull_ack_message_operation_count` would be the number of messages acknowledged via ack requests.